# How to comment out only code lines and not existing comments

Tags: comments

I use `vim-commentary` to comment. Hit `g-c-c` to toggle comments. But this will comment out the already existing comments if they start with `//` and it will comment out already existing comments startin with `/*`.

Is there a way (with / or without a pluging) to comment out lines of code while ignoring the already existing comments in the specified block?

Comment: Your question could most probably benefit from an example (or a couple.) By "ignoring" the existing comments, do you mean preserving them when commenting the block? Or nesting them inside a separate comment block (ignoring they were already commented while commenting them)?

Comment: It is the same for me if the existing comments will be ignored or commented out again. Important is that when I un-comment the block again they will come back as a normal comment. I think the best option is to comment them out again.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) plug-in, which offers mappings with finer granularity.

See [the default mappings](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter#default-mappings), you have `<Leader>cc` to *comment* a block of code (not toggle) and also `<Leader>cn` to comment the code, but forces nesting (which makes it easier to uncomment the block and keep the pre-existing comments as such.)

You can override the default mappings by setting the global variables from the documentation in your vimrc.

Comment: Yeah, comment comments is a feature imo. Makes it easier to uncomment later.

Answer (score 1):

The [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin uses `'commentstring'` to define what a comment should look like. Some languages support multiple comment formats, e.g. `//` & `/* */`. Change `'commentstring` to match the format that you use

```
set commentstring=//%s
```

However, if a project uses two different formats then you can still it becomes more challenging. I would then suggest making mappings which set `'commentstring'` and then rest it after the commentary command is given with the `CommentaryPost` autocmd:

```
function! s:AltCommentary()
  let s:commentary_format = &commentstring
  let &commentstring = '// %s'
  augroup alt_commentary
    autocmd!
    autocmd User CommentaryPost let &commentstring = s:commentary_format |
          \ autocmd! alt_commentary
  augroup END
endfunction

xmap <leader>gc  :<c-u>call <SID>AltCommentary()<cr>gv<Plug>Commentary
nmap <leader>gc  :<c-u>call <SID>AltCommentary()<cr><Plug>Commentary
nmap <leader>gcc :<c-u>call <SID>AltCommentary()<cr><Plug>CommentaryLine
```